# Groovy copy file, modify values and save it

Tags: groovy

I need to use Groovy to copy a "template" file and replace some text (a variable) with current values and then save the file in a new file.

```
bay_equipment.each{

  hname="Network-${it['hostname']}-${it['function']}" 
  nodeName="${it['hostname']}"
  nodeIP="${it['ip_address']}"
  fname="${it['hostname']}-${it['function']}-Network.cfg"
  

  def src= new File("../config-files/nagios-switch-bayg20.cfg")
  def dst= new File("../dest-files/$fname")
  dst << src.text
```

//everything work ups to here

//now trying to open the dst file and make modifications then save it.

//This string <%=@deviceType%>-<%=@deviceGroup%>-<%=@nodeName%> needs to be replaced with hname variable and likewise the <%=@nodeIP%> with nodeIP

```
  dst = (dst =~ /<%=@deviceType%>-<%=@deviceGroup%>-<%=@nodeName%>/).replaceFirst("$hname")
  dst = (dst =~ /<%=@nodeIP%>/).replaceFirst("$nodeIP")
  
  dst.write(dst)
  
  
}
```

I'm getting an error when I run it:

Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.String.write() is applicable for argument types: (String) values: [../dest-files/u100en00700-BAYG20-Network.cfg]
Possible solutions: wait(), wait(long), with(groovy.lang.Closure), trim(), size(), toSet()
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.String.write() is applicable for argument types: (String) values: [../dest-files/u100en00700-BAYG20-Network.cfg]
Possible solutions: wait(), wait(long), with(groovy.lang.Closure), trim(), size(), toSet()
at nsr_nagios$_run_closure4.doCall(nsr_nagios:53)
at nsr_nagios.run(nsr_nagios:38)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Separate the part of replacing the content and writing the file (e.g. read the source into a string, manipulate the string, write the string at the end).  As of now you are turning "dst the file" into "dst the string".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an example of how you can work with this, the following code:

```
def equipment = [
  [hostname: 'foo',   function: "bar",   ip_address: '1.2.3.4'],
  [hostname: 'alice', function: "raven", ip_address: '5.6.7.8']
]

equipment.each {
  def binding = [
    hname:    "Network-${it['hostname']}-${it['function']}",
    nodeName: it.hostname,
    nodeIP:   it.ip_address,
    fname:    "${it['hostname']}-${it['function']}-Network.cfg"
  ]  

  def srcData  = new File("src-file.txt").text
  def template = new groovy.text.StreamingTemplateEngine().createTemplate(srcData)

  new File(binding.fname).text = template.make(binding)
}
```

given the following source file:

```
<%= hname %>-<%= nodeName %>-<%= nodeIP %>
```

will create two files, both templated. Example execution sequence:

```
─➤ ls -la 
total 24
drwxrwxr-x   2 mbjarland mbjarland  4096 Mar  4 17:55 .
drwxr-xr-x 112 mbjarland mbjarland 12288 Mar  4 17:47 ..
-rw-rw-r--   1 mbjarland mbjarland   634 Mar  4 17:55 solution.groovy
-rw-rw-r--   1 mbjarland mbjarland    42 Mar  4 17:55 src-file.txt

─➤ cat src-file.txt 
<%= hname %>-<%= nodeName %>-<%= nodeIP %>

─➤ groovy solution.groovy 

─➤ ls -la 
total 32
drwxrwxr-x   2 mbjarland mbjarland  4096 Mar  4 17:56 .
drwxr-xr-x 112 mbjarland mbjarland 12288 Mar  4 17:47 ..
-rw-rw-r--   1 mbjarland mbjarland    33 Mar  4 17:56 alice-raven-Network.cfg
-rw-rw-r--   1 mbjarland mbjarland    27 Mar  4 17:56 foo-bar-Network.cfg
-rw-rw-r--   1 mbjarland mbjarland   634 Mar  4 17:55 solution.groovy
-rw-rw-r--   1 mbjarland mbjarland    42 Mar  4 17:55 src-file.txt

─➤ cat foo-bar-Network.cfg 
Network-foo-bar-foo-1.2.3.4

─➤ cat alice-raven-Network.cfg 
Network-alice-raven-alice-5.6.7.8

─➤
```

where the template engine is a [groovy built in class](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/next/html/documentation/template-engines.html) for doing just these kinds of things.